# CSS3 -webkit-linear-gradient creating darker vertical lines than expected

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create a grid in pure CSS using background-image and -webkit-linear-gradient. I have the spacing and the tiling working fine, but for a reason I can't figure out, the vertical lines are coming out as #B8B8B9 instead of #E3E4E5 like I specify. Any ideas?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2faSt/

CSS:

```
.grid {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #e3e4e5 0px, transparent 1px, transparent 15px, #e3e4e5 16px, transparent 16px, transparent 99px, #e3e4e5 100px, #ffffff 100px), -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 20px, #e3e4e5 20px);
    background-size: 111px 21px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get really the color that you specify, you should set **2** color stops with the same color, separated by at least 1 px.

Otherwise, you set only the point of gradient change, but it is already changing to transparent, even in the same pixel

And, even it is non intuitive, transparent if **black** transparent (rgba (0,0,0,1))

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QtLh8/1/)

There, you have this CSS:

```
#one {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #e3e4e5, transparent);
}

#two {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #e3e4e5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
}
```

In the first div (The same color stops that in your question), you can see that in the middle of the transition the color is **darker** than at the beginning.
As a comparison, in the second you can see what probably you intended, make the transition to white transparent.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the 2 stops. I got it to work with:

`background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #e3e4e5 0px, #e3e4e5 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 15px, #e3e4e5 15px, #e3e4e5 16px, transparent 16px, transparent 99px, #e3e4e5 99px, #e3e4e5 100px, #ffffff 100px), -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff 0px, #ffffff 20px, #e3e4e5 20px);`
<br/><br/>
[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2faSt/4/)